# Pay Users with PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms

I see a lot of information on using PayPal as a checkout option on your website. However, I can't seem to find any concrete information on using PayPal to pay your users. I'm looking for the correct API to do this in an ASP.NET application.

I found [this](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/v1.5.0/README.md) on NuGet, but I don't know if it accomplishes what I need. So, which API should I be looking at in order to pay users using PayPal? Which information will I need from them in order to pay them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with `AdaptivePayments`, which allow for direct payment from your account (therefore requiring no approval). [THIS](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox#credentialsModal) is the guide I found most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Classic API has something called [MassPay](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside). This pays anyone via PayPal (or email) but it costs up to $1 to use.

Comment: How does it compare to AdaptivePay?

Comment: No clue. All I know is it takes your PayPal balance and sends it to another PayPal account.